# whereshould i put this code for creating a tile

Tags: windows-phone-7

i want to set  secondry tile in my app but i don't know where i put code  of secondry tile because it show unhandled exception and my  App does not run it back

```
var foundTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("DetailId=123"));

if (foundTile == null)
{
    var secondaryTile = new StandardTileData
    {
        BackgroundImage = new Uri("Images/SecondaryTileFrontIcon.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
        Title = "hiiiiiiii",
        Count = null,
        BackTitle = "",
        BackContent = "byeeeee ",
        BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Images/ApplicationTileIcon.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
    };

    ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/Views/DetailsPage.xaml?DetailId=123", UriKind.Relative), secondaryTile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each tile is identified by the `Uri` supplied to `ShellTile.Create`. In your case, you're not creating a secondary tile, but checking if the **same** tile already exists, and if it's not, then you create it.

If you want more than one tile, you need to use different uri's for the `ShellTile.Create` call, typically with different query-string parameters/values.

And you obviously shouldn't make it dependant on the uri of completely unrelated tile.